# How to properly wrap texture on to gameobject at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-shaders

The scale of my gameobject is 1,1,1 in x,y,z respectively I am scaling the gameobject to 1000,1,1 in x,y and z respectively at runtime.

After scaling the gameobject i create a new UV mesh using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40002421/6833276) as reference and apply Texture to my gameobject the output is totally different from what i expect.

I tried to apply texture using 3D builder app on object and texture wraps well as shown in the image below. 
[image]

But the output from my code is as shown below

1) Front view : The texture wrapping is really bad
[image]

2) Side view : The texture is wrapped but is repetitive

[image]

To overcome this wrong wrapping, I tried to rotate the texture using shaders but the output is improper. What am i doing wrong? Which is the best method to evenly apply texture on all sides of the gameobjects?

Comment: Do you have correct UV?

Comment: I am a newbie in unity texture and UV, How do i check if my UV is correct?

Comment: you can try to apply some check mate texture or try to check it with other programs